# Grunt plugin not overwriting task level options

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-plugins

The [GruntJs docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) say that target level options should overwrite task level options.

I have built a plugin, [grunt-esri-slurp](https://github.com/steveoh/grunt-esri-slurp), where I would like to have multiple targets (local dev and for travis ci). I have noticed that the task level options are not being overwritten by the target level options.

```
esri_slurp: {
  options: {
    version: '3.10',
    beautify: true
  },
  travis: {
    options: {
      beautify: false,
      version: '3.9'
    }
  }
}
```

when i run `grunt esri_slurp:travis` `3.10` is passed in as well as `beautify`. I used a yeoman generator to create the plugin and I don't know if I have to do something in the plugin itself to make this work. [This would be the offending code](https://github.com/steveoh/grunt-esri-slurp/blob/master/tasks/esri_slurp.js#L24-L28) I would imagine.

Is this a grunt bug or developer/user misunderstanding/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [change](https://github.com/steveoh/grunt-esri-slurp/blob/d7690e3b9baf50a927982f4371814cc536fc3e9a/tasks/esri_slurp.js#L23) your [`grunt.registerTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) call to [`grunt.registerMultiTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask), as that's the one that supports target options.

Make sure to read the [`this.options` docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.options).

Comment: so if I do that then if you run the task with no target it doesn't seem to use the task level options? Is that because it iterates through all of the targets or something. I feel like I read that somewhere.

Comment: Target options overrides task options. See updated answer. Omitting the target will execute all the targets in order.